# Expose a class to Python and change it in Python as well

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I've used Boost.Python to expose my class into Python. I want to change this class or override some parts of it in Python as well as what we can do on classes in Python by default.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make a subclass, like:

```
class Subclass(MyBoostPythonClass):
     # your modifications / extensions ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to subclass, which would be the other answer provided; however if you are looking to change an objects class on-the-fly, you could use `object.__class__ = NewClass` -- though this may be considered EVIL in some (probably most) circles.